# Am I overloading my opencl kernel? My screen goes blank while running the code

Tags: opencl, gpu, ati, jocl

My kernel function has to store an intermediate private array with 7500 values. While running the code my screen goes blank for a second and when it resumes results are not displayed. Assuming that there is not enough private memory, I changed the code a little. Now it compares each new array value with the biggest value computed so far. So that I need not create an array of 7000 values. Instead I store only the biggest value. But still I get the same issue. So what might the reason for my screen going blank?
This is my kernel:

```
__kernel void sampleKernel(
    const uint trgr,
    const uint trgc,
    __global const float *TRG,
    __global const float *ENT,
    __global float *RES1,
    __global float *RES2)
{
    int pred, tars, preds;
    float big1, big2;
    float g1 = 0, g2 = 0;
    float tol = 0.5f, val = 0.0f;
    int i  =  get_global_id(0);
    for(pred = 0; pred<trgr; pred++)
    {
        val = 0.0f;
        for(tars = 0; tars<trgc; tars++) 
            {
            for(preds = 0; preds<trgc; preds++)
            {
                if(TRG[pred*trgc+preds] > (TRG[pred*trgc+tars]-tol) && TRG[pred*trgc+preds]>(TRG[pred*trgc+tars]+tol) )
                    val = val+1;
            }
        }

        val = ENT[pred]*val;
        if(pred == 0) 
        {
            big1 = val;
            g1 = pred;
        }
        else if(pred == 1)
        {
            if(val>big1)
            {
                big2 = big1;
                g2 = g1;
                big1 = val;
                g1 = pred;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(val>big1)
            {
                big2 = big1;
                g2 = g1;
                big1 = val;
                g1 = pred;
            }
            else if(val>big2)
            {
                big2 = val;
                g2 = pred;
            }
        }
    }
    RES1[i] = g1;
    RES2[i] = g2; 
}
```

stored in `private static String programSource;`. And here is the code:

```
 //writing to GPU
 clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, Sizeof.cl_uint, Pointer.to(new int[]{7000}));
 clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, Sizeof.cl_uint, Pointer.to(new int[]{36}));
 clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[0]));
 clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[1]));  
 clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[2]));
 clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[3]));

 //reading from GPU
 clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[2], CL_TRUE, 0, m * n * Sizeof.cl_float, pres1, 0, null, null);
 clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[3], CL_TRUE, 0, m * n * Sizeof.cl_float, pres2, 0, null, null);
```

Comment: Generally, __private memory is rather limited, but if the problem persists when you don't reserve a large private array, it must be somewhere else. You'll need to post code to get help.

Comment: As you can see, this code doesn't overload private memory.

Comment: Fix the formatting.... why wouldn't you have the kernel in a seperate file?! Are you getting any output?

Comment: I am using JOCL. I don't get output from GPU kernel code. But the java  part of my code which runs on CPU gives output. ok, I have changed the format now.

Comment: You are not copying buffers to gpu and read back.

Comment: I guess there are no problems in R/W data. I have edited the post.

Comment: Based the symptoms that you are describing, you're almost certainly accessing invalid memory regions (and the "blank screen" is the OpenCL version of an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ;-)). At least, you are passing **arrays** to the kernel as the first two arguments, but from the kernel signature, these should be (single) **uint** values. Most likely, these `uint` values will contain "the address" of the array, which could screw up your computations.

Comment: If your kernel takes more than a short time (3 seconds?) to run, the OS will terminate it. The screen may flash when that happens. If your kernel is kill the system instantly, and not after a few seconds, it is something else. Try running your kernel on a smaller data set to debug it, and then grow it to the large size.

Comment: Yeah, it takes a few seconds before going blank

Comment: You are doing 3 nested for loops inside each WI. Unless each of them takes a few instructions only that is clearly a lot of work. Possibily not achievable in less than a few seconds. BTW, you are just running 1 WI?? You don use the variable i at all...